# Possible vulnerability in ProFTP 1.3.3e

Tags: security, pci-compliance, proftpd

I'm managing a PLESK server and got this error from a client after they did a PCI scan on their site. What is ProFTP and is this really an issue? How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: First hit on google for "vulnerability in ProFTP 1.3.3e"  http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-9520/product_id-16873/version_id-82841/Proftpd-Proftpd-1.3.3.html

Comment: @IanMcLaird I already read this page. It doesn't explain what ProFTP is or how to fix the vulnerabilities.

Comment: It's an FTP server.  You fix the vulnerabilities by upgrading it to a version that no longer has the vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Proftpd version 1.3.5 is used in latest version of Plesk. Please, consider upgrade possibility.

Answer (score -1):

I don't mean to sound harsh but you are managing a Plesk server and you don't know what ProFTPd is? Its an FTP server. FTP is File Transfer Protocol and is the protocol used to upload web pages to websites. The version you are using is out of date and has more than one known vulnerability which could mean your server gets compromised. I'd recommend you upgrade.